# Проверка e-mail в imput

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Есть простой скрипт на проверку E-Mail юзера. Если все нормально введено, то скрипт уменьшает прозрачность импута и добавляет зеленый бэкграунд. Если нет, то добавляет красный бэкграунд. Проблема в том, что если вначале ввести в строку что-нибудь не соответствуещее регулярному выражению(кроме пустоты), то при последующем изменении поля бэкграунд на зеленый не изменится. А вот, если вначале вводить e-mail соответствующий регулярному выражению, то фоны отлично меняются. Вопрос в чем, что тут не правильно то и почему не меняется фон если ввести вначале что-нибудь не правильно?

```
$('#mail').blur(function () {
    var a = $(this).val();
    var regular =  /[-\w.]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}/;
    if (a == '') {
        $(this).fadeTo(500, 1).addClass('newmail');  
    }
    else if (a.search(regular) == 0) {
        $(this).fadeTo(400, 0.6).addClass('newmailyes');
    }
    else if (a.search(regular) == -1) {
        $(this).fadeTo(400, 0.6).addClass('newmailno');    
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.newmailyes {
    background: #e1fbda;
}
.newmail {
    background: #fff;
}
.newmailno {
    background: #ffdedb;
}
```

Comment: попробуйте вместо .blur() использовать [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: К сожалению, беда осталась(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

да потому что addClass('newmailno') добавляет класс 'newmailno', но потом нигде ни при каких условиях этот класс не убирается (как, впрочем, и другие).
А в css этот класс идёт последним по очереди при равной специфичности. Вот он и применяется.

```
$('#mail').blur(function () {
var a = $(this).val();
var regular =  /[-\w.]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}/;
if (a == '') {
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 1).removeAttr("class").addClass('newmail');  
}
else if (a.search(regular) == 0) {
    $(this).fadeTo(400, 0.6).removeAttr("class").addClass('newmailyes');
}
else if (a.search(regular) == -1) {
    $(this).fadeTo(400, 0.6).removeAttr("class").addClass('newmailno');    
}
```

});

Но это только если никаких других значимых классов нет у вашего элемента.
Иначе надо что-то в таком духе будет:

```
$(this).fadeTo(400, 0.6).removeClass("newmail").removeClass("newmailno").addClass('newmailyes');
```

Comment: Точно!
Спасибо.
Я в JS новичек, не подскажете ли вы, как удалить все классы у объекта? removeClass?

Comment: вызов .removeClass() без параметров удалит все css классы у выбранного элемента.

Comment: Большое спасибо!
Все получилось!

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="email" required />
```

Comment: Самый правильный ответ. Для старых браузеров подпирается чем-то в духе [HTML5-Form-Shim](https://github.com/dsheiko/HTML5-Form-Shim) (их много таких, на выбор).